# Find the palindrome of a string by using python

Tags: python

I would like to find the longest palindrome from a given string.

then print it

```
lines = "forgeeksskeegfor"
length = len(lines)
a = [lines[i:j+1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i, length)]

total = []
for string in a:
    list(string).reverse()
    reverse_String = "".join(string)

    if reverse_String == string.lower():
      total.append(reverse_String)
print(max(total))
```

My current output:
    sskeegfor

expected should be:

```
geeksskeeg
```

this is length 10 and the longest

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindromic-substring-set-2/ Go through this if you have any doubts then ask

Answer (score 1):

There are two palindrome scenarios: Even palindromes (e.g. noon) and Odd palindromes (e.g. radar).  There are only two possible (longest) palindromes for each position in the string.  So, for each position, you only need to find the longest Even and Odd palindromes centred at that position by comparing characters forward and back.

```
s = "forgeeksskeegfor"

from os import path 
longest = ""
for i in range(1,len(s)-1):
    if min(i,len(s)-i)*2+1 <= len(longest): continue
    for odd in [1,0]:
        if s[i+odd] != s[i-1]: continue
        halfSize = len(path.commonprefix([s[i+odd:],s[:i][::-1]])) 
        if 2*halfSize + odd > len(longest):
            longest = s[i-halfSize:i+halfSize+odd];break
print(longest) # geeksskeeg
```

*Note: this could be further optimized but will respond in O(n) time most of the time or up to O(n^2/2) in the worst case scenario where the string contains very long chains of identical characters (or only a single repeated character)*

**UPDATE**

In order to minimize the impact of long chains of identical characters, the order of center positions for potential palindromes could follow a binary search pattern.  The binRange() generator below can be used to replace `range(1,len(s)-1)` with `binRange(1,len(s)-1)` in the main loop.  This will ensure that longer palindromes are found early and shorter embedded ones can be short circuited in subsequent iterations.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def binRange(lo,hi=None):
    if hi is None: lo,hi = 0,lo
    if hi <= lo: return
    mid = (lo+hi-1)//2
    yield mid
    for a,b in zip_longest(binRange(lo,mid),binRange(mid+1,hi),fillvalue=None):
        if a is not None: yield a
        if b is not None: yield b
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of looking for max of a list of 'strings' , you should look for maximum length.
based on your approach.

```
lines = "forgeeksskeegfor"
length = len(lines)
a = [lines[i:j+1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i, length)]

total = []
for string in a:
    if string == string[::-1]:
        total.append(string)
max_len = max( [ len(x) for x in total ] )
# result list will contain the longest pallindroms
result_list = [ x for x in total if len(x) == max_len ]
```

There is some flaw in your palindrome check.

```
for string in a:
    # the below line will not change anything
    # you are just converting a string to list on the fly 
    # reversing it ,but not storing it somewhere
    list(string).reverse()
    # string is still string of a , and reverse_String and string
    # both will be same.
    reverse_String = "".join(string)

    # not sure why are you converting to lower here
    if reverse_String == string.lower():
      total.append(reverse_String)Hope it helps
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But the result I printed is different from what I expect

Comment: updated my answer, actually when you are doing list(string).reverse() it's not changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with dynamic programming

The following code has a worst running time of 2^n when there is no palindrome in the string, so it will try all possible solutions.
But its performance increases as it finds a palindrome.

```
def find_pal(string, start, end):
    # base case
    if end - start <= 1:
        return (start, end)
    # if a palindrome shows:
    elif string[start] == string[end]:
        # check if its substring is a palindrome also
        next_pal = find_pal(string, start + 1, end - 1)
        if next_pal == (start + 1, end - 1):
            # if it is, then return the longer
            return (start, end)
        else:
            # if it is not, still return any smaller palindrome in string
            return next_pal
    else:
        # if this string is not a palindrome, check for a smaller in a  substring
        next_pal1 = find_pal(string, start + 0, end - 1)
        next_pal2 = find_pal(string, start + 1, end - 0)
        if next_pal1[1] - next_pal1[0] > next_pal2[1] - next_pal2[0]:
            return next_pal1
        else:
            return next_pal2


def find_greatest_pal(string):
    pal_pair = find_pal(string, 0, len(string)-1)
    return string[pal_pair[0]:pal_pair[1]+1]


print(find_greatest_pal("forgeeksskeegfor"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to iterate through the string and generate all palindromes starting from the center and moving out to the two sides. If we find a palindrome greater than our current length, we replace it with the new one.

```
def longestPalindrome(s):
    ans = ""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for k in range(2):
            temp = helper(s, i, i + k)
            if len(temp) > len(ans):
                ans = temp
    return ans

def helper(s, l, r):
    while l >= 0 and r < len(s) and s[r] == s[l]:
        l -= 1
        r += 1
    return s[l+1:r]
```

Usage:

```
print(longestPalindrome('forgeeksskeegfor'))
geeksskeeg
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way, this function can help you:

```
def longest_palindrome(text):
    text = text.lower()
    longest = ""
    for i in range(len(text)):
        for j in range(0, i):
            chunk = text[j:i + 1]
            if chunk == chunk[::-1]:
                if len(chunk) > len(longest):
                    longest = chunk
    return longest


print(longest_palindrome("forgeeksskeegfor"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a substring can be 1 character long (this can be easily modified in the check length conditional) and there could be potentially multiple longest strings with the same length:

```
def longest_substring(string):
    longest = ""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(string) + 1):
            sub = ''.join(string[i:j])
            if str(sub) == str(sub)[::-1]:
                if len(sub) > len(longest):
                    longest = sub

    return longest
```