# Write a program that finds the longest palindromic substring of a given string. Try to be as efficient as possible

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that finds the longest palindromic substring of a given
string. Try to be as efficient as possible!
I wrote the program but it needs improvement

```
A=input("write?")
def longestPalindrome(A):
    rev = A[::-1]
    l = len(A)
    while l > 0:
        for i in range(0, len(A) - l + 1):
            half = int(l / 2)
            left = A[i : i + half]
            right = rev[len(A) - (i + l) : len(A) - (i + l - half)]
            if left == right:
                return A[i:i+l]
        l -= 1
    return None
print (longestPalindrome(A))
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55486770/5237560

Comment: For a second I thought I was still over at [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). I see you're new here, so welcome aboard. This stack exchange deals [mainly with code issues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); if your code is working and you just want open-ended advice on how to improve it, [the code review stack exchange exists for that](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code.

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter
sam = 'abcbarascalacsarijkl'
palindrome = []
for i,j in filter(lambda x: x[1] >1,Counter(sam).items()):
    indexes = [index  for index in range(len(sam)) if sam[index] == i]
    for cm in combinations(indexes,2):
        substr = sam[cm[0]:cm[1]+1]
        if substr==substr[::-1]:
            print('palindrome')
            palindrome.append((substr,len(substr)))
sorted(palindrome,key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0][0]
```